# PHP contact form not retrieving results from <select> option from dropdown menu

Tags: php, email

Need help figuring out why PHP is not retrieving data from drop down list. Sends message with value as "undefined"
---HTML---
`<select name="amount" id="amount" title="Please choose dollar amount.">`
`<option value="">- Choose dollar amount from a list -</option>`
`<option value="25">$25</option>`
`<option value="50">$50</option>`
`<option value="75">$75</option>`
`</select>`

---PHP---
`//vars`
`$amount = $_POST['amount'];`

`//data`
`$msg .= "AMOUNT: " .$_POST['amount'] ."<br>\n";`

`//send for each mail`
`foreach($to as $mail){`
`mail($mail, $subject, $msg, $headers);`

Comment: If your form method POST? What is your echo value on $amount?

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your <form> code